# Blocking IP address ranges in a Windows 7 VM under Virtual Box

Tags: windows-7, ip, firewall

Using Windows 7 installed in a virtual machine built with Virtual Box 4.3, I have created two Inbound and Outbound firewall rules. I need to block two ranges of IP address in the VM.

[image: IP ranges rule]

However, doing for example a ping gives:

[image: ping result]

As you can see 4 pings were sent and received, so were not blocked.

Any suggestions on how to block these IP ranges in my Windows 7 VM and why I still get a connection?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Quite possibly your firewall rules are working correctly while ping is allowed via [these kind](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aopy) of rules for the ICMP protocol. You might be using the wrong tool to test the firewall. Try instead a better-adapted product such as the free [Nmap](https://nmap.org/) and be careful with your IP addresses.

Comment: I assume that the subject here is the firewall in the guest VM.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, true. I would like to block this IP, just from the guest VM.

Comment: Test the firewall with nmap rather than ping and report on the results.

Answer (score 1):

We need more information about your firewall rule : Which protocol it applies-to (should be "Any"), which ports (should be "All"), whether the rule blocks or
allows connections (should be "Blocked") and  whether the rule is enabled.

Please post screenshots of the rule's details of the tabs of "General" and
"Protocols and ports", in addition to the one you posted of the
"Scope" tab.

If these were set correctly, then quite possibly your firewall rules are working
as defined, while ping is allowed via [rules applied to the ICMP protocol](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aopy)
(the protocol used by ping).

If the rules are working correctly, the source of the problem might be
that you are using the wrong tool to test the firewall.
Try instead a better-adapted product such as the free [Nmap](https://nmap.org/), and be careful
with your IP addresses.

<sub>(Because of lack of response by the poster to comments, this is the best answer I could come up with the little information that was supplied
in the post.
More information will allow me to better improve this answer.)</sub>

Comment: The rules should be `All` and `Any` for all the settings.